# hbase keeps crashing on my mac air

Tags: macos, hbase

```
2014-12-06 19:34:55,487 DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: Looked up root region location, connection=org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation@180231d3; serverName=localhost,49174,1417889923478
2014-12-06 19:35:26,248 FATAL org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster: master:49170-0x14a20d303610000 master:49170-0x14a20d303610000 received expired from ZooKeeper, aborting
org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$SessionExpiredException: KeeperErrorCode = Session expired
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ZooKeeperWatcher.connectionEvent(ZooKeeperWatcher.java:384)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ZooKeeperWatcher.process(ZooKeeperWatcher.java:303)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$EventThread.processEvent(ClientCnxn.java:519)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$EventThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:495)
2014-12-06 19:35:26,248 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster: Aborting
2014-12-06 19:35:26,248 WARN org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.SplitLogManager: Interrupted while waiting for log splits to be completed
2014-12-06 19:35:26,248 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn: EventThread shut down
2014-12-06 19:35:26,248 DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster: Stopping service threads
2014-12-06 19:35:26,248 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.HBaseServer: Stopping server on 49170
2014-12-06 19:35:26,248 WARN org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.SplitLogManager: error while splitting logs in [file:/tmp/hbase-mokal/hbase/.logs/localhost,49174,1417889923478-splitting] installed = 2 but only 0 done
2014-12-06 19:35:26,249 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.HBaseServer: IPC Server handler 0 on 49170: exiting
2014-12-06 19:35:26,249 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.HBaseServer: IPC Server handler 2 on 49170: exiting
2014-12-06 19:35:26,249 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.HBaseServer: IPC Server handler 3 on 49170: exiting
2014-12-06 19:35:26,249 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.HBaseServer: IPC Server handler 5 on 49170: exiting
2014-12-06 19:35:26,249 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.HBaseServer: IPC Server handler 7 on 49170: exiting
2014-12-06 19:35:26,248 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster$2: localhost,49170,1417889908118-BalancerChore exiting
2014-12-06 19:35:26,249 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.HBaseServer: IPC Server handler 8 on 49170: exiting
2014-12-06 19:35:26,250 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.HBaseServer: REPL IPC Server handler 1 on 49170: exiting
2014-12-06 19:35:26,249 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.HBaseServer: IPC Server handler 6 on 49170: exiting
2014-12-06 19:35:26,249 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.HBaseServer: IPC Server handler 4 on 49170: exiting
2014-12-06 19:35:26,250 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster: Stopping infoServer
2014-12-06 19:35:26,249 WARN org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.CatalogJanitor: Failed scan of catalog table
java.io.IOException: Giving up after tries=1
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ServerCallable.withRetries(ServerCallable.java:210)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.MetaScanner.metaScan(MetaScanner.java:188)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.MetaScanner.metaScan(MetaScanner.java:82)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.MetaScanner.metaScan(MetaScanner.java:67)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.CatalogJanitor.getSplitParents(CatalogJanitor.java:126)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.CatalogJanitor.scan(CatalogJanitor.java:137)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.CatalogJanitor.chore(CatalogJanitor.java:93)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.Chore.run(Chore.java:67)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.InterruptedException: sleep interrupted
        at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ServerCallable.withRetries(ServerCallable.java:207)
        ... 8 more
2014-12-06 19:35:26,249 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.HBaseServer: IPC Server handler 1 on 49170: exiting
2014-12-06 19:35:26,252 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.CatalogJanitor: localhost,49170,1417889908118-CatalogJanitor exiting
2014-12-06 19:35:26,252 INFO org.mortbay.log: Stopped SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:60010
```

Comment: So, what's your question?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear. But since you're running HBase on MacBook Air, I'm assuming it's for academic purposes or to 'try out stuff'. In that case, I would ask you to use a QuickStart VM. I would suggest one of below:

1. [Cloudera QuickStart VM](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/downloads/quickstart_vms/cdh-5-2-x.html)
2. [HortonWorks Sandbox](http://hortonworks.com/products/hortonworks-sandbox/)

Your MacBook Air's 4GB RAM would not be enough to run your VM smoothly. But, people have been able to run VirtualBox successfully on MacBook Air and it's a good start for you.